# Changing data source for all layers in MXD?

Tags: arcmap, layers, esri-geodatabase, data-source

I have an MXD.  It connects to about 30 layers in one of our SDE databases.  I want to change the SDE database they connect to.

Is there a way to do this without having to right-click every layer and change it individually?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Right click on the mxd in ArcCatalog, click on Set data sources, and bulk change from there. However, this tool warns:

> Note: this dialog is intended primarily for preparing map documents for publication. Customizations (VBA code, UI Controls and custom toolbars), graphs, and table window appearance properties are removed from .mxd files when you update their data sources using this dialog. To preserve these, update the data sources in ArcMap instead.

You could also use the [arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000004p000000) python library:

Comment: This seems to not work in 10.1. The data source is changed, but (at least in the case of an SDE connection) the link is changed to a "database connection", i.e. the layer isn't being pointed to any longer, which breaks the link.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using ArcGIS 10 and are interested in using Python, check out the help on [Updating and fixing data sources with arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000004p000000) and the methods of the [Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) object.

Example:

```py
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\Project_SDE1.mxd")
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"Database Connections\Connection to GISSDE1.sde", 
                                r"Database Connections\Connection to GISSDE2.sde")
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Project_SDE2.mxd")
del mxd
```

If your layers don't all source the same original connection file, or the destination feature class name is different on the new SDE, you might need to use `Layer.replaceDataSource` instead.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks!
One thing to add is "Database Connections\Connection to GISSDE1.sde" can be replaced with a .gdb location too.

Comment: How would I be able to use this from switching the data source from the SAME SDE but from version 1 to version 2?

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a data source connection in ArcCatalog.
2. Open the MXD and expand the layer and click on the red exclamation mark in any layer. This will open a popup window containing the data source with database connection.
3. Select the database connection that you had made, double-click on that and go inside that to the layer that you have clicked and select that layer and press OK, Open or Add.

This will remove all the red exclamation mark containing layers in the MXD and will point to the new created data source. In one go you can do this; no need to go and click each time on the red exclamation mark and clicking and setting the data source.

Comment: Its very helpfull.Please go throug this once

Comment: This will only work if the connections are broken, otherwise one of the other answers are more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14922

The link is to an old Arcscript called GDK tools, wich can be obtained on other sites.
The Program creates a toolbar in arcmap where you can change source on selected layers (any layer you want. this works between SDE connections or SDE to local file geodatabase (wich change source in Arccatalog not can handle, because of the name in SDE starts with the SDE user and then dot.

this is very helpful, but maybe only in arcgis 9.3

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I Have modified!

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the .mxd open already, do what @blah238 did, but use `'CURRENT'` instead of the full path. Don't forget that the search and replace doesn't have to be the full string:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"scratch", 
                                r"project/draft")
```

Then you'll have to save and reopen the .mxd file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For one mxd, default ESRI tools can suffice. But fixing multiple mxds with broken links can be a nightmare. Try my UpdateLayerRefs tool to fix unlimited MXDs in seconds: https://github.com/jswagger/UpdateLayerRefs 
Just provide the names of your input MXD's as a list 
["Name1.mxd", "Name2.mxd", "Name3.mxd"]

Comment: Nice sharing your code :) Can you elaborate a bit on how one can use it ?

Comment: Absolutely:
1. Fill out JSON config file:

Comment: First step, i guessed ! But i'm wondering about after - Seems your comment didn't hit the ground for the rest of the message. You should maybe edit your answer instead :) :)

Comment: By reading the github i realized what was missing. Filling up the json makes the UpdateLayerRefs.py file usable anywhere, isn't it ? So one just needs to go to the UpdateLayerRefs.py folder then run in a cmd window "python UpdateLayerRefs.py" ?

Comment: Sorry, got pulled off on something. Updating the readme file now....

Comment: That is correct. Running 
python UpdateLayerRefs.py --config "update_layer_refs.config.json"
allows you to run it in any folder.

Comment: Just for my understanding, if one would like to enhance your coding  : by using a check on the workspace type, do you think it would be possible to adapt any type of workspace (filegdb, sde, simple folder) and maybe change the paths accordingly ? This way you could have new config items, like folder_in folder_out, filegdb_in, filegdb_out, etc. and change them at the same time depending on their type ?